# Does the 'X' of Grignard's reagent react?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Till whatever I have studied in organic chemistry, Grignard's reagent has been the most helpful thing everywhere, whether is it preparation or reaction of organic compounds. But I haven't ever seen the *Halogen* part of *RMgX* reacting with any compound. Does the *Halogen* ever react in any reaction?

Comment: Maybe it does, it's just those reactions are not that helpful, so nobody uses them.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at Grignard's reaction route. Key step is nucleophilic addition of R. And MgX is removed with acid on the next step. Nobody cares about X - if you want MgX2 in solution you just add MgX2. The main reason to use Grignard's reagent is nucleophilic addition of R.

[image]